# Наследование JS

Tags: javascript, наследование

Вот код:

```js
function Animal (name) {
 this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.getName = function(name) {
 console.log(this.name);
};

function Dog (name) {
 Animal.apply(this, arguments);
 // this.name = name;
}

Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;

Dog.prototype.bark = function(name) {
 console.log('Dog ' + this.name + ' is barking');
};

var dog = new Dog('Aban');
// dog.bark();
// dog.getName();

console.log(dog.getName() === 'Aban'); // false
console.log(dog.bark() === 'Aban'); // false
```

Почему возвращает false, а не true?

Comment: Так у вас там ни чего не возвращается, чего вы хотите-то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как `getName()` и `bark()` ничего не возвращают. Вот примерно так нужно:

```js
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.getName = function(name) {
  console.log(this.name);
  return this.name;
};

function Dog(name) {
  Animal.apply(this, arguments);
  // this.name = name;
}

Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;

Dog.prototype.bark = function(name) {
  console.log('Dog ' + this.name + ' is barking');
  return 'Dog ' + this.name + ' is barking';
};

var dog = new Dog('Aban');
// dog.bark();
// dog.getName();

console.log(dog.getName() === 'Aban'); // false
console.log(dog.bark() === 'Aban'); // false
```

Comment: Zualex, спасибо за подсказку!